# Getting Error in animation of polylines in Google Map using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, csv

I am new to Google Maps and Javascript. I am working on a project in which I have to plot a moving path on the map using the latitudes and longitudes. I have more than 76000 coordinates. So I tried the explanation on this link-:[Animate route on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001206/animate-route-on-google-maps)

I have a .csv file for my coordinates. If I have hardcode the values I get the map. When I am trying to import my .csv file and plot the map i get errors.

I am getting the following error messages-:
(1) Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(2) InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

```
    lat,lon,loc
    29.718922,-95.339162,UH
    29.71683047,-95.40166506,RU
    30.0575359,-95.1902986,KW
    29.748425,-95.677353,GB
    29.739545,-95.462716,GL



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Animated route</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
     v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() 
    {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
        {
          center: {lat: pathCoords[0].lat, lng: pathCoords[0].lng},
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        autoRefresh(map);
    }


    function moveMarker(map, marker, latlng) 
    {
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
        map.panTo(latlng);
    }


    function autoRefresh(map) 
    {
        var i, route, marker;

        route = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            geodesic : true,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            editable: false,
            map:map
        });

        marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:"http://maps.google.com/
        mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"});
        for (i = 0; i < pathCoords.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function (coords)
            {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
                route.getPath().push(latlng);
                moveMarker(map, marker, latlng);
            }, 2000 * i, pathCoords[i]);
        }
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    var pathCoords=[];
    d3.csv("houston.csv", function(data)
    {
        data.map(function(d)
        {
            pathCoords.push([d.lat,d.lon]);


        })
        console.log(pathCoords);

    });

    /*var pathCoords = [
        {
        "lat": 29.718922,
        "lng": -95.339162
        },
        {
        "lat": 29.71683047,
        "lng": -95.40166506
        },
        {
        "lat": 30.0575359,
        "lng": -95.1902986
        },
        {
        "lat": 8.52426,
        "lng": 76.93668000000001
        }
    ];*/
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="map"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: This is not how SO works. The methodology is that you show us your code and tell how it is or is not meeting the requirements.

Comment: @lit I have updated this post with my code and the error messages which I am getting. Can you please go through to it and let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: @duncan Can you please look into this code and provide some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you've got an extra blank line at the end of your .csv file.

```
Line number Content
76809       30.6420046,-96.4751224
76810       30.6420046,-96.4751224
76811       30.6420046,-96.4751224
76812
```

Delete that last line and it should work without error.

```
Line number Content
76809       30.6420046,-96.4751224
76810       30.6420046,-96.4751224
76811       30.6420046,-96.4751224
```

Comment: I am trying to do mouseover on the google map path and also to resume the path after pausing it. have posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082870/not-able-to-resume-and-do-mouseover-on-google-path-using-javascript. Can you please go through it. Thanks a lot!